# What is the biggest sword a human could effectively wield?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, humans, weapons

There are small swords and big swords. Fiction often uses **really** big swords. What is the largest [sword](/questions/tagged/sword) a human could effectively wield, unaided?

Comment: It might be useful to clarify your  human - are we looking for the biggest sword an *average* human can use, or are we looking for Andre the Giant's weapon?  You also need to specify tech level, as that will impact weight.

Comment: See, if you were on the moon..

Comment: @dot_Sp0T - Even on the moon, the mass of the sword would be an important factor. While you were slowly swinging your super-enormous weapon, someone could run in with a dagger and puncture your space-suit.

Comment: Are we allowed modern composite materials or must we use metal? If so, what metals are allowed?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK that basically renders all sword-wielding useless as you can simply pull an [Indiana Jones](https://youtu.be/4DzcOCyHDqc)

Comment: @dot_Sp0T - Well yes but I was assuming hand-to-hand. We need clarification.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I was trying to humorously point out that the questions is merely about the *ability* rather than the *implications* :)

Comment: Hmm.... could this be Engineering.SE instead?

Comment: You're asking about extreme swords, but I did want to point out that there are other extreme weapons.  Wing Chun actually has an entire form dedicated to fighting using a 10 foot long bamboo pole.

Comment: Relevant to the question: [Forging the Buster Sword](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xogheZdAO18). 6 ft long, 1 wide, ~80 lb. They also made [Sephiroth's Masamune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ySQratOnwk) which is 7 ft katana like sword. Spoiler, the Masamune would win in a fight, mostly because you can swing it more than once. Lastly, you could effectively use swords bigger than Buster simple by using a powered exoskeleton or power armor. But at that point it's kinda silly.

Comment: The point (ha ha) of a large, heavy sword is to get more mass behind the edge to help it break through armors and shields.  If you lighten the material, you are correspondingly decreasing its effectiveness if it does hit anything.

Comment: @Oldcat I remember a story about battles during the crusades. The knights would come in with their 6 ft long swords, take massive, limb cleaving swings. If they missed, the Turks would come in with their shorter, lighter, faster swords and take the knights to pieces. In all things, there are trade-offs.

Comment: But a huge, long sword made of light metal still won't be fast to swing. So they gain little for that particular tradeoff, as they keep the drawbacks and discard the advantage.

Answer (score 4):

It depends what it is made of.

There is "a new class of magnesium-alloy syntactic foam that always floats on water ... one of the strongest metals for its weight ever developed."   http://motherboard.vice.com/read/one-of-the-strongest-lightest-metals-ever-made-is-less-dense-than-water

If we can find out the density of that material we can calculate the size for the weapon by knowing how heavy it could plausibly be.

UPDATE - Reading further, I see that the density is about the same as that of water, i.e. 1kg/m3.

There is an article [here](http://www.thearma.org/essays/2HGS.html#.VcIbcV7bIuQ) (thearma.org) about the weights of actual medieval swords. They were lighter than some people suppose.

It turns out that the calculation is incredibly easy. Steel is about 8 times the density of water. If we assume that traditional swords are made of steel then all we have to do is find an actual length for a steel sword and (in order to keep everything in the same proportion) multiply it by the cube root of 8  (i.e. 2).  So, by reading that article I see that a very large usable steel sword would be at most 6 feet long. Therefore our alloy sword could be 12 feet long. It would look something like this.

[image]

**Answer**

Steel sword - about 6ft

Super-light alloy sword - about 12ft

Comment: Water weighs roughly 1kg/l

Comment: @dot_Sp0T -  True -  I've added that to my answer.

Comment: One question though is how hard the alloy is? Steal isn't just strong, but hard, while still being a little flexible too. Your 12ft sword isn't worth much if my 6ft sword can just cut right through it. Bronze is harder and more durable than iron, and similar to mild steel. A sword made of gold would look pretty, but be torn to pieces instantly because of the softness.

Comment: @AndyD273 -  Sadly they don't say in the article. It does say this though, "Gupta...said it was one of the strongest metals for its weight ever developed."  If you wish to suggest a better alloy then the calculation is still easy. However the question wasn't about the effectiveness of the sword. It was about the largest size that someone could wield.

Comment: You could probably improve the strength by layering in harder metals like steel, and use high carbon steel for the cutting edges. That way the alloy just fills in and gives it strength, like a bone, and the steel does what it does best. They used to do something similar with bronze. Hard bronze for the edges, softer bronze for the rest. To make it harder to break I think...

Comment: Remember that it's not just weight, but inertia.  A long, slender sword is going to have more rotational inertia than a short, broad one of the same mass.  So it takes more effort to set it in motion, or change the direction of motion, which means the wielder will be pretty much limited to slow slashing, without parries or feints.

Comment: @jamesqf - I'm not quite convinced yet. Could you show the maths? (Incidentally I admit that air resistance would be greater). Does rotational inertia of a rigid object change with length rather than with mass? Mass must have some effect.

Comment: @ chasly, if you want to hold a sword horizontally at a single point, and keep the top from dropping, you need to provide a moment of inertia equal and opposite to that provided by gravity. This is effectively the sum, for each atom, of the mass multiplied by the distance from the pivot point (the hands holding the sword). However, we can simplify it from there, if we know where the centre of mass is, we can pretend all of the mass is at that exact point. It turns out to give exactly the same answer. So a sword that is twice as long but weighs the same will have twice the moment of intertia.

Comment: So if you make it x times as long, it will have weigh more by x^3 as identified in the post, but the centre of gravity will be x times as far away. So the moment of inertia will be x^4 as high. To make the moment of inertia no higher, we then need to set x^4 = 8, so x~=1.685, so the sword is 10 ft long.

Comment: Note, the above assumes that you hold the sword at the very end of it. This is not completely accurate, particularly as some swords have deliberately weighted pommels. The reason they do this is to add weight on the other side of the pivot point - the sword acts like a see-saw, if you hold a sword out, the weight of the blade acts to move the tip downwards, but the pommel acts to move the tip upwards, partially counteracting this. If you want to know mroe on how it works, I suggest you visit here, or similar

https://myarmoury.com/talk/viewtopic.php?t=3189

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Water actually weighs EXACTLY 1kg/l

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner *no*. Water weighs ever so slightly under a kilogramm per liter. It even gets lighter the warmer it gets.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK stumbling by accident over this answer again, there's a mistake in it: You imply the density of water being at about 1kg/m3 in your 4th paragraph. This is wrong. The density of water is at about 1kg/dm3 - that is 1000 times denser, as a m3 fits 10x10x10 dm3

Comment: 12 foot weapons made of a material lighter than metal were common in warfare. They are called spears or pikes and they are made of wood. Spears and pikes cannot be swung like swords. The centre of gravity is too far from the handle. What you have designed here is a funny-looking spear.

Answer (score 0):

First it really depends on the size of the human wielding it.  Some the size of [Andre the Giant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_the_Giant) could wield a much larger sword than say, [Verne Troyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verne_Troyer).

The [Claymore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claymore), a Scottish long sword averaged 4-5 ft. in length, the blade 3-4 foot long. The Ōdachi is a long Japanese sword up to 6ft in length and was most often used from horseback, to give a longer reach.

So in theory, someone the size of Andre the Giant my be able to wield a sword 8-9ft long.  It would be slow, but powerful.  No blocking, either get out of the way or die.